# Is this full outer join correct?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am developing a `CGridView` which contains a checkbox. This checkbox is selected if, in the next query, the field `SELECT_PRIV` equals to `Y`.

The query I am developing has two tables. One of them is mine and contains a list of objects in the DB, the object type, and the project related with the object. For example one row is:

```
ID      OBJECT_NAME        OBJECT_TYPE  PROJECT
--      -----------        -----------  -------
1   F_XXX_TEST_FUNCTION     FUNCTION      XXX
2   F_YYY_BETA_FUNCTION     FUNCTION      YYY
3   F_ZZZ_FINAL_FUNCTION    FUNCTION      ZZZ
```

The other table is an oracle table: `USER_TAB_PRIVS`. Each row of this table contains the relation between each user and each object. For example, if any user doesn't have grants on the `F_XXX_TEST_FUNCTION` it won't appear in this second table. On the other hand, it will appear if some user has any type of grants.

Sample data:

```
GRANTEE        TABLE_NAME         PRIVILEGE
-------        ----------         ---------
 user5    F_XXX_TEST_FUNCTION      SELECT
 user1    F_YYY_BETA_FUNCTION      SELECT
 user5    F_XXX_TEST_FUNCTION      DEBBUG
 user1    F_YYY_BETA_FUNCTION      DEBUGG
 user2    F_ZZZ_TEST_FUNCTION      SELECT
 user4    F_YYY_BETA_FUNCTION      SELECT
```

Then, I am trying to compute when one extra field should have `Y` or `N` according to if the relation exists or not. If it exists, the user has grants. If not, the user does not have those grants.

The table that I would like to get is:

```
   OBJECT_NAME         OBJECT_TYPE    PROJECT   GRANTEE   SELECT_PRIV
   -----------         -----------    -------   -------   -----------
F_XXX_TEST_FUNCTION     FUNCTION        XXX      user1         N
F_XXX_TEST_FUNCTION     FUNCTION        XXX      user2         N
F_XXX_TEST_FUNCTION     FUNCTION        XXX      user3         N
F_YYY_TEST_FUNCTION     FUNCTION        YYY      user1         Y
F_YYY_TEST_FUNCTION     FUNCTION        YYY      user2         N
F_YYY_TEST_FUNCTION     FUNCTION        YYY      user3         N
F_ZZZ_TEST_FUNCTION     FUNCTION        ZZZ      user1         N
F_ZZZ_TEST_FUNCTION     FUNCTION        ZZZ      user2         Y
F_ZZZ_TEST_FUNCTION     FUNCTION        ZZZ      user3         N
```

My logic says: You need to `select * from your table`, and the do a `case` that evaluates if the relation exists in the oracle table or not. I have some parameters, like type of object, user to check grants and only search for `execute` or `select` grants, so the query is this one:

```
      SELECT  OL.OBJECT_NAME, OL.OBJECT_TYPE, OL.PROJECT, UT.GRANTEE,
               CASE WHEN EXISTS (
             SELECT GRANTEE, TABLE_NAME
               FROM USER_TAB_PRIVS UTP
              WHERE UTP.GRANTEE IN ('user1','user2','user3')
                AND UTP.PRIVILEGE IN ('SELECT','EXECUTE')
                    )
               THEN 'Y'
               WHEN EXISTS (
             SELECT *
               FROM  "V_AWP_OBJECTS_LIST" "O"
          LEFT JOIN USER_TAB_PRIVS UT 
                 ON UT.TABLE_NAME=O.OBJECT_NAME
              WHERE O.OBJECT_NAME IS NULL
                    )
               Then 'N'
                    END AS SELECT_PRIV
               FROM "V_AWP_OBJECTS_LIST" "OL"
    Full outer join USER_TAB_PRIVS UT 
                 On UT.TABLE_NAME=OL.OBJECT_NAME -- OUTTER
              WHERE OL.OBJECT_TYPE IN ('FUNCTION') 
                AND UT.GRANTEE IN ('user1','user2','user3')
                AND UT.PRIVILEGE IN ('SELECT','EXECUTE')
```

The problem with this query is that it does not show a list of all functions stored in `V_AWP_OBJECTS_LIST`, and the extra column with `Y` or `N` in function if the user has grants or not.

Can anyone help me? I do not know how build properly this query.

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell without your data. btw you should avoid double-quotes - they aren't actually doing any harm here but they aren't helping either, and they are generally risky.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your tips. Now I will add some data as example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I understand correctly, for every row in `v_awp_objects_list`, you want to display one row per user listed in your `IN` clause: `IN ('user1','user2','user3')`.  To do that, you additionally need to have some sort of temp table with the user list so that you can join on that.  For that reason, you will notice the `user_cte` that uses `SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL` to convert a list of usernames to rows that can be joined on.

Otherwise, the query just needs a `left join` on `user_tab_privs`, not a `full outer join`. And it also needs a `group by` clause to make sure we don't get more than 1 row per function/user combination. Hopefully this works:

```
with user_cte(username) as (
  select column_value
    from table(SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL('user1', 'user2', 'user3'))
)
select o.object_name, o.object_type, o.project, u.username,
       case when count(p.table_name) = 0 then 'N' else 'Y' end as select_priv
  from v_awp_objects_list o
  cross join user_cte u
  left join user_tab_privs p
    on p.table_name = o.object_name
   and p.grantee = u.username
   and p.privilege in ('SELECT', 'EXECUTE')
 where o.object_type = 'FUNCTION'
 group by o.object_name, o.object_type, o.project, u.username
```

Comment: Thanks sstan for your answer and corrections.  You understand it well. Now I am not in my work, but I will try tomorrow and tell you if it works. Thank you again!

Comment: sstan, it works! Thank you very much. I have some questions that I would appreciate if you answer to learn a little about this query:

-The with clausule is to create a virtual table, but why you use those parentheses?

-How is the transition between the virtual table and the select? I mean you first build the virtual table and then you do the select and specify the cross join later. I understant that it is like a little procedure, right?

-What table is SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL? I guess that it is a table to select some predefined values.

Comment: Another question:
-The count(p.table_name) works over the full user_tab_privs table or works over the left join table build? 

Thank you.

Comment: You can think of the `with` clause as a view that is built on the fly for use anywhere in the main query. See here for more info on that: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause. The use of `SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL` is a bit of an obscure trick to convert a list of hardcoded values into a table. See here for more info on that one: http://ora1034.blogspot.com/2013/01/dbmsdebugvc2coll.html.  And finally, yes, `count(p.table_name)` only counts rows in `user_tab_privs` if they are fetched by the left join.  If the left join returns null, because a row does not exist, it isn't counted.